# Lua compiled in C++ throw for each yield making debugging complicated

Tags: c++, c, exception, lua, clion

Lua compiled in C++, so it uses `throw` instead of `setjmp` for errors.
This is all good, until I realized not only it `throws` on errors, but when a coroutine yields too, or I miss something. So when I want to debug and enable **Pause on exception** on **CLion**, my game pause every frame because coroutines are heavily used. So, how can I disable **CLion** to pause for Lua exception only ? I can't achieve to do that. This simple reason itself is sufficient to convince me to compile Lua in C.

As an auxiliary question, doesn't that pause a performance problem, as exceptions are regulary blamed for performance especially for games ?